# Do not retrieve query if empty output

Tags: function, google-sheets, filter, google-query-language

In this sheet I'm working on, I'd like only the applicable data to show on the Teacher1Results tab, not the #N/A for empty output. Secondly, is it possible to make a >= into, for example >=4 but also <=8? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ToeDdavA-red9tH40jqFmcv8soQ-pgwICcZPZOUUHNY/edit?usp=sharing Thank you so much in advance for helping such a noob. I'm learning every time I get an answer and really appreciate the time you all spend helping people like me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Teacher1Results!A13 for example try:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(Teacher1!A17:P17, "select A where P >=9 and P <20")
```

---

### update:

delete everything in range Teacher1Results!A11:A and use this in Teacher1Results!A11:

```
=FILTER(Teacher1!A15:A, Teacher1!P15:P>=9, Teacher1!P15:P<=21)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's better already, as it removed the #N/A, but now I'm getting lots of blank cells. The part about
and P <20
just clears all the data though.

Comment: @SarahSavoy answer updated

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much!! It's neat, clean, and easy to understand.